# jQuery - Trouble passing a variable into input:radio[name]

Tags: jquery, variables, input

I'm having trouble passing a variable in the following

`var whichRbClicked = $('input:radio[name=RBname]:checked').val();`

where RBname is the variable.

Any help or advise would be MUCH appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

```
var whichRbClicked = $('input:radio[name=' + RBname + ']:checked').val();
```

For more info, check out:

- [Concatenating strings with the + operator](http://www.scriptingmaster.com/javascript/concatenating-strings-javascript.asp)